# При попытке старта селеноид контейнера с новыми параметрами получаю ошибку, что с таким именем контейнер уже существует, как это фиксится?

Tags: linux, docker, selenide

Есть список docker контейнеров.
[image: Есть список docker контейнеров.]
Контейнер selenoid работает с параметрами:

```
"-service-startup-timeout",
            "10m",
            "-session-attempt-timeout",
            "10m",
            "-session-delete-timeout",
            "5m"
```

Мне нужно выставить **-session-delete-timeout 10m.**
Выполняю команду **sudo ./cm_linux_amd64 selenoid start --args "session-delete-timeout 10m"** (предварительно останавливаю selenoid контейнер)
Получаю ошибку:

```
Failed to start: failed to create container: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/selenoid" is already in use by container 15fc4feaaf050575eb36e73c7c3a1b156bf7adbe56c559287f97f2498b307b1a. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

1) Я правильно понимаю, что мне надо удалить контейнер с именем selenoid_selenoid_1 (судя по скрину)?
2) Не совсем понятно, почему при старте пытается создаться новый контейнер (судя по ошибке), мы ведь стартуем уже существующий контейнер, который просто в стопе находится. Т.е. я либо не совсем понимаю, что делает команда, либо некорректная ошибка
3) Опасаюсь, что, возможно, потеряются какие-то важные настройки. Или при новом старте контейнера по образу всё должно восстановиться?
4) Если какая-то другая последовательность действий должна быть, то какая?

Документация по команде cm: https://aerokube.com/cm/latest/

Comment: Ну если у вас такая ошибка то  очевидно что вы не запускаете остановленный контейнер, а пытаетесь запустить (создать) новый.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно не верно стартуете контейнер, не путайте команды `docker start` и `docker run`.
Проверьте все контейнеры `docker ps -a` Скорее всего имя занято остановленным контейнером. id контейнера на скрине не совпадает с логами, начните с этого.